# Is it possible to change font of bluetooth printers?

Tags: java, android, printing, bluetooth

I've bought a Bluetooth printer for my android device and I need to print in cp1256 (arabic) the model I've bought is RPP-02 which is not loaded with middle eastern fonts.

I just wanted to know is it possible to change internal font these kind of printers?

Comment: Ask the printer manufacturer.

Comment: (un)fortunately its chinese, not quite sure if they answer such questions thoroughly.

Comment: I am from China, if the menu is Chinese then I can look it to see whether it support change font.

Comment: Thank you for such offer, there is no menu in bluetooth printer. there is a driver which we have to use inside our android app and then send ESC commands. thats all.